# Control active view via property

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, mvvm

I have built a good working WPF-application which is mvvm compliant. I have one window, in which I am controlling via a property(public Object named CurrentHomeView) which Datatemplate will be shown. For example: If my property equals LoginViewModel, the window will display the LoginControl which is a UserControl. So far so good.
Now I want to take this system and use it in a xamarin app. But the way I made it in my WPF-application seems not to be the right way in xamarin.

What do I have to do, that it will work the same way?

You will the in my code, what I have built so far. My ContantPage is not changing the constant.

My Class to manage the value of my property:

```
namespace Core.ApplicationStartUp
{
    public class StartUp : BindableBase
    {
        LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;

        private bool _isNewUser;
        private object _currentMainView;

        public object CurrentMainView
        {
            get => _currentMainView;
            set => SetProperty(ref _currentMainView, value);
        }

        public bool IsNewUser
        {
            get => _isNewUser;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isNewUser, value);
        }

        public StartUp()
        {
            _isNewUser = SearchUserData();
            if (!IsNewUser)
                LoadLoginControl();
        }

        private bool SearchUserData()
        {
            return false;
        }

        private void LoadLoginControl()
        {
            _loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel(this);
            bool isIn = _loginViewModel.CheckStatus();
            if (!isIn)
                CurrentMainView = _loginViewModel;
            else
                _loginViewModel.Login();
        }
    }
}
```

`

My Window in the WPF application:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loginCore:LoginViewModel}">
            <loginControl:LoginControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type registrationCore:RegistrationViewModel}">
            <registrationControl:RegistrationControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type navigationCore:NavigationViewModel}">
            <navigationControl:NavigationControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="White">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentMainView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
```

And this is my Page in Xamarin, which should use the same Class to mage the active View:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:navigationControl="clr-namespace:Mobile.Areas.Navigation"
             xmlns:navigationCore="clr-namespace:Core.Areas.Navigation;assembly=Core"
             xmlns:registrationCore="clr-namespace:Core.Areas.Registration;assembly=Core"
             xmlns:registrationControl="clr-namespace:Mobile.Areas.Registration"
             xmlns:loginCore="clr-namespace:Core.Areas.Login;assembly=Core"
             xmlns:loginControl="clr-namespace:Mobile.Areas.Login"
             x:Class="Mobile.MainWindow">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type loginCore:LoginViewModel}"
                      x:Key="LoginControl">
            <loginControl:LoginControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type registrationCore:RegistrationViewModel}"
                      x:Key="RegistrationControl">
            <registrationControl:RegistrationControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type navigationCore:NavigationViewModel}"
                      x:Key="NavigationControl">
            <navigationControl:NavigationControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <ContentView Content="{Binding CurrentMainView}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I do not get any exceptions or errors. Further more there is no information in the output.

Comment: ,According to your description, you want to display different UI when one property changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to a WPF `ContentControl` in Xamarin.Forms. You could create a custom `ContentView` as suggested [here](https://oren.codes/2014/12/31/contentpresenter-for-xamarin-forms/):

```
public class ContentPresenter : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ContentPresenter), null, propertyChanged: OnItemTemplateChanged);

    private static void OnItemTemplateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var cp = (ContentPresenter)bindable;

        var template = cp.ItemTemplate;
        if (template != null)
        {
            var content = (View)template.CreateContent();
            cp.Content = content;
        }
        else
        {
            cp.Content = null;
        }
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

There is also no support for implicit data templates. You can work around this by using a [converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) as suggested [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2017/03/25/uwp-implicit-data-template/).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to reuse your ViewModels from WPF app in Xamarin app - this is doable, but not easy.

The way you did view switching in WPF works and is OK, but it is not "how it's done" when you want to go multiplatform.

First thing you should do, is to make sure that ViewModels are platform agnostic - put them all in a PCL. Proper MVVM app should be able to run and do stuff even without any views attached - this includes switching the active ViewModel.

You achieve this by using Navigation/Routing service - most MVVM frameworks have that. Basically, it is a thing that you ask to show some ViewModel - if you want to learn a lot, write your own, otherwise use of the existing, it's not worth your time to invent it one more time. How the VM is shown depends on what platform the program is running - there should be no difference from VM point of view though. Still, you will need seperate Views (UserControls in WPF, Pages in Forms) for each platform.

One of the best MVVM frameworks in my opinion is [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/), written with Xamarin in mind, so it's fast, has low startup time etc. It also works with most platforms: WPF, WinForms, Windows Universal Apps, even Avalonia and some others. RxUI even supports views activation out of the box which is more than handy. Also, once you go reactive, there is no way back :)

[This](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/) article conveys the basics of the routing concept.

Happy digging from there :)